# Is there any reason why setting a managed .NET client to use STA threads would cause problems with exceptions in a native COM server?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, com, exception, com-interop

I have a native (Delphi) COM server that is advertised as STA (Apartment Threaded Model).

It contains a few algorithms that throw overflow exceptions in some cases. These exceptions are handled in the code, and everything works as it should if I access the COM server from a client on the main thread.

If the client is native (Delphi), I can access the server from multiple threads as long as I stick to the rule that an object created on a thread makes all it's method calls from that same thread.

However if the client is a managed client (Vb.NET and C# tested), if I set the ApartmentState of the client threads to MTA, everything works fine, but I get a performance hit.

This I expect, as I guess COM must be doing some jiggery pokery (i.e. marshaling) to make sure everybody is happy.

However if I change the ApartmentState to STA, and thus ensure a direct connection between client and server, the client will crash with a fault error, usually a System.stackoverflowexception in CustomMarshallers.dll.

If I eliminate the numbers causing these overflow's then I have no problems.

I can get round this by tweaking the algorithms to not depend on exceptions (probably how they should have been written in the first place), but I would like to understand the reasons behind what is happening.

Comment: Your code must be thread-safe in STA.

Comment: The code is thread safe. All instance data is safe as it is guaranteed to be called from a single thread. All global data has been protected.

Comment: Not trivial  but running the COM server under debugger could help

Answer (score 0):

There is some amount of guesswork involved in this answer given that you do not quote the error message verbatim and mention no HRESULT values.

There is a theoretical possibility that the different available stack space between the STA and MTA cases would make a difference to a stack hog of a Delphi application.  But the following possibility is more likely.

The `StackOverflowException` is likely caused by the Delphi side itself (supposing that the error message calls it "unhandled").  Look closer at all error handling mechanisms on the Delphi side and watch for any mechanisms that could lead to recursion specifically on errors.  For example, code executing on a particular event might contain a guarded block where the catch clause does something that triggers that same event.

I suppose that the difference that you see with STA versus MTA would somewhat level out if you remove the `PreserveSigAttribute` from the client code, so that the stack overflow exception will stop being translated into an HRESULT that your client presumably ignores right now.  (If you used `tlbimp.exe`, this attribute got specified implicitly.  It means that you want to handle exceptions the COM way as return values, not the .NET way as exceptions.)

Comment: All valid points no doubt, but why does the native client handle this with no problem. I have a specific line in one of my algorithms :

Comment: : if a[icol,icol] = 0 then raise EMatrixError.Create('Matrix Error'); I am trying to handle this error, but as the exception unravels, I get the error. So yes, the error in the Delphi code, but something in the .NET client seems to cause the problem

Comment: @Steve - re "client crashes with fault error", can you copy and paste the message or stacktrace that you see?  Did you try printing out the HRESULT from the Delphi (unmanaged) client, that the client probably ignores right now?  If my answer is correct, that HRESULT will be an error code, and `PreserveSigAttribute` will be the only difference between the two clients.

Comment: I don't even get as far as HResult. The error happens as the exception starts to unroll. In fact it doesn't even get as far as my handler. It's as if the .NET client is interfering with the stack somehow of the unmanaged server.

Comment: @Steve - but in the question you wrote that when the client is Delphi, you can call the server from multiple threads without crashing.  And I'm asking you to modify your Delphi client to print the HRESULTs that it is currently ignoring (or to display them via debugger).